# Rally Request Entity Too Large

Tags: rally, appsdk2, lookbackapi

Due to the limitations of the lbapi as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930854/lookback-api-return-visible-work-items-only), my queries to the lbapi have drastically increased in size (I am passing an array of "visible" projects to the LBAPI which will only return work items from projects which I have view access to) to the point where I get a "Request entity too large" error.

I know I need to break up my queries by only using some of the visible projectsat a time.  I wanted to do this programatically - for every 100 visible projects, do a query, take the records that come back and throw them into an array.

However, this gets kind of messy when I am trying to determine when to continue - have all of the queries come back and populated the array of totals?  Can anyone think of a clean way to make this happen?

```
for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(App.visibleTeams.length / 100); i++) {
    console.log('i',i);
    var tempProj = [];
    for (var j = i * 100; j < Math.min((i + 1) * 100, App.visibleTeams.length); j++) {
        tempProj.push(App.visibleTeams[j]);
    }
    console.log('tempProj.length',tempProj.length);
    // query
    App.completeRecords = [];
    Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        pageSize : 10000,
        fetch    : ['Parent','Name','_UnformattedID','PortfolioItemType','PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate','ObjectID','PlannedStartDate','PlannedEndDate','ActualStartDate','ActualEndDate','LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal'],
        filters  : [{
            property : '__At',
            value    : 'current'
        },{
            property : '_TypeHierarchy',
            value    : 'PortfolioItem'
        },{
            property : '_ItemHierarchy',
            operator : 'in',
            value    : node.ObjectID
        },{
            property : 'Project',
            operator : 'in',
            value    : tempProj
        },{
            property : 'LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal',
            operator : '>',
            value    : 0
        }]
    }).load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            if (!success) {
                Ext.getBody().unmask();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error ' + operation.error.status + ': ' + operation.error.statusText, operation.error.errors[0]);
            } else {
                App.completeRecords.push.apply(App.completeRecords, records);
                // if done, callback(), else, do nothing
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution works, its just messy.  Thanks everyone for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added some new functionality that will address this. I added a more detailed response to the other question that you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930854/lookback-api-return-visible-work-items-only).